# Is there a way to pass the file location by jndi in a <util:properties /> tag?

Tags: java, spring, jndi

I have the following properties declared in my spring-config.xml

```
<util:properties id="ldap" location="classpath:com/company/project/resources/some_configuration.properties"/>
```

Then I inject the values contained in the properties into some member variables using the spring `@Value` annotation in a service implementation (this approach is by far the cleanest/most elegant I have used in the implementation of the service and if possible I wouldn't want to change it).

The problem with this layout is that I have to modify the properties file and regenerate the application war for every deployment environment (quality, production, etc) and the server admins want to configure the `some_configuration.properties` path by JNDI (the application server is JBoss)

How can I pass the file location by jndi in the `<util:properties />` tag?

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated

**edit:**
It would be nice if somebody comes out with a solution where I could do something like:

`<util:properties id="ldap" location="jndi:url/some_configuration.properties"/>`

Or similar

Comment: If your are using Maven2, you can use the `maven-antrun-plugin` on `prepare-resources` Maven's phase to filter your `some_configuration.properties` by Maven Profile (dev1, dev2, test, preprod, prod). I have done it before.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using Maven2 for the project

Comment: which development tools are you using? Apache Ant?

Comment: Eclipse Dynamic Web Project from WTP

Comment: Check my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10727450/439427

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old post, but this may be useful for others:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="ldapProps" jndi-name="your/jndi" resource-ref="true"/>
<util:properties id="ldap" location="file://#{ldapProps}/some_configuration.properties" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for! We've being resorting to other methods to achieve something similar

Comment: Same - I got sufficiently frustrated today by our workarounds to be motivated enough to get JNDI to work :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking something similar, this answer will help you using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3486315/439427.

HTH

---

In your case you will need to configure the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in your beans then you will just need to do the following change:

```
<util:properties id="ldap"
  location="classpath:x/y/z/resources/${environment}.properties"/>
```

Where `${environment}` will be set by an environment variable like this: `-Denvironment=dev`

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking it, but I still would like to know if there is a way of doing the same by jndi

Comment: I like the approach, but if the server configuration changes (port, ip, domain, etc), I have to edit the properties files and regenerate the war, something that the admin team don't want to, they want to edit an external file so they don't need the developer assistance for the task (if they could do it by jndi would be a big plus because they already have a jndi capable server)