# Spring properties priority

Tags: java, spring, properties, intellij-idea

I've got standart maven folder structure:

```
src/main/java  
src/main/resources  
src/test/java  
src/test/resources
```

My appicationContext contains following:

```
<!-- load properties files -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>
```

I have defined 2 `hibernate.properties` files - one for `src/main/resources` and one for `src/ test/resources`. I have expected that when I will run tests my test `hibernate.properties` will override production `hibernate.properties`. Instead of that both files are loaded and production version is used:

```
Loading properties file from file [D:\projects\video_crawler_v3\out\test\core\hibernate.properties]
Loading properties file from file [D:\projects\video_crawler_v3\out\production\core\hibernate.properties]
```

How can I correctly setup my properties files? I'm using Intellij IDEA to compile and run tests

Comment: Can you add an example of your `hibernate.properties` file? I just want to see the kind of differences between your main and test configuration. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that naming property placeholder configuration file  `hibernate.properties` is a great idea, `hibernate.properties' is typically a configuration file of Hibernate itself and has nothing to do with Spring property place holders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is Spring Profiles http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Put two "properties" versions in your context.xml, eg:

```
<beans>

   ... your beans

    <beans profile="prod">
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/hibernate.properties" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="test">
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/test-hibernate.properties" />
    </beans>
</beans>
```

Activate required profile with -Dspring.profiles.active=test.

Note: use www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd

Comment: You should demonstrate how Spring Profiles is a solution here. Also a caveat: the feature is only available from Spring 3.1 and greater.

Comment: you could use `@ActiveProfiles("test")` instead of `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` if you are using TextContext framework http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

Answer (score 1):

The files in src/main/resources are always added to the classpath, even when running the unit tests. See this: [Common strategies when defining Spring beans for different environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484591/common-strategies-when-defining-spring-beans-for-different-environments)