# How to create bean by double reference?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I do not know how to articulate/search the issue in the first place.

So the bean initialized are :

```
<bean id='domain' factory-bean='appConfig' factory-method='getDomain'/
<bean id='prod' class='java.lang.String'> <constructor-arg value='Base.Prod'/> </bean>
<bean id='test' class='java.lang.String'> <constructor-arg value='Base.Beta' /> </bean>
```

Now I need to create a bean "X" using the value of Prod or Test depending on the value of domain. If domain is Prod,use the bean of Prod to initialize bean X else use Test.

${${domain}} does not work. I tried searching but was not able to find a question that meant this.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3486315/6239524

Comment: My code is not appearing in the block code.

Comment: @Enigmagirl, put it in code formatter block, not in blockquote.

Comment: Thank you @M.Prokhorov !

Comment: You dont need to create 2 different bean. You can with one bean and create 2 properties file.if you have more properties to change

Comment: @kalsowerus, I agree that creating xmls based on environment is much better to maintain xmls but at this point, there is only one bean and I feel it is too much work for it.

Comment: @Enigmagirl which version of spring you are using ?

Comment: @soorapadman, explanation with example will help. Unable to understand how it will solve my problem

Comment: @soorapadman, even with newer version it would not matter I believe because there is no concept which can be used to initialize that bean . To answer your question, project has latest support to Spring 4 but it contains xmls which are written previously.

Comment: @Enigmagirl i'm sure you can do with beans  `<beans profile="prod">
        <bean id='prod' class='java.lang.String'> <constructor-arg value='Base.Prod'/> </bean>
        
    </beans>
    <beans profile="test">
    <bean id='test' class='java.lang.String'> <constructor-arg value='Base.Beta' /> </bean>
        
    </beans>` use same bean id for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. There is a way to refer the test/prod bean through domain. You just got to use #{domain}. More information here: [spEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

Use it as :

```
<bean id="ThatBean" class="whicheverClass">   
 <constructor-arg ref="#{domain}" /> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
@Value("${domain}")
private String domain;
```

Combined with

```
-Ddomain=dev
```

Spring adds any system properties to properties read from properties file.

Comment: I am using older version of Spring. So they are XML based

Comment: @Enigmagirl the Value annotation is the same, it's unaffected by XML or Java config.

Answer (score 1):

@EssexBoy's answer in XML would look something like this:

```
<bean id="domain" class="java-lang.String">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>${domain}</value>
    </construcotr-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: ${domain} will give the value of the domain bean. But what I want is , get the value of the bean whose name is the value stored in domain bean. 

Domain = prod /test
So based on domain value, I would want to refer to prod bean or test bean

Comment: @Enigmagirl Your prod/test beans are both Strings, why won't one String with either value work?

Comment: Either of them will work. When I get the value of domain as Prod, I want Base.Prod to be assigned for Bean X, when domain value is test then I want Base.Beta to be assigned for Bean X. 

It is conditional and I do not know how conditional is handled when using xmls

Comment: @Enigmagirl including different XMLs for each environment might be the only option if you can't use the value of `${domain}` directly...

Comment: Alas! I wonder how conditional beans were handled before. Like if something is null, then initialize a bean with abc value, else initialize xyz value.